# AttributeError: module 'scikitplot' has no attribute 'plot_precision_recall_curve'

Tags: python, scikit-learn, scikit-plot

With the following code, I'm getting the error `AttributeError: module 'scikitplot' has no attribute 'plot_precision_recall_curve'`.

```
rfc = RandomForestClassifier(verbose=True) #uses randomized decision trees
rfcmodel = rfc.fit(X_over, y_over)
y_pred = rfc.predict(X_test)

print ("Score:", rfcmodel.score(X_test, y_test))
print("Confusion Matrix: \n", confusion_matrix(y_test, y_pred))
getStatsFromModel(rfc)
```

How can I solve this?